# Именованные колонки запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, python

Код:

```
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute("select * from payments where month(pay_date)=month(now())  and year(pay_date)=year(now()) and amount>=1000 limit 1");
     num_fields = len(cursor.description)
     field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
     pprint.pprint(field_names);
     row = cursor.fetchone()
     while row is not None:
       print(row[0]);
       pprint.pprint(row);
       row = cursor.fetchone()        
    conn.close()
```

работает. Как в строке  `print(row[0])` сделать что-то врооде            `print(row["agrm_id"]);`?

Comment: Вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565487/python-mysql-fetch-array рекомендуют использовать fetchall.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы получить результат в виде словарей:

```
cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute('ваш запрос')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row['название столбца'])
```

Comment: Но таким способом загружается в память весь результат запроса?

Comment: да, но Вы можете в свой код при создании курсора передать параметр: MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, и получать результат не в виде кортежей, а в виде словарей.

Answer (score 0):

У меня заголовки таблицы хранятся в виде кортежа в отдельной переменной:

```
headsru=("ID", "Задача", "Подзадача", "Сотрудник", "Дата", "Статус", "Коммент", "Тек статус", "Осталось")
```

Сначала вытягиваем таблицу как список кортежей:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Далее выводим имена столбцов, они идут в строгой последовательности (кортеж ведь), 
а потом через цикл поочередно вставляем строки. Они вставятся корректно (опять же каждая строка - кортеж)

На примере Tkinter:

```
table["columns"] = headsru # создаем заголовки
...
for i in result:
    table.insert('', END, values=(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7], i[8]))
```

Если через консоль, то точно так же выводим заголовки:

```
h = ("ID", "Task", "Subtask", "Employee")
print(h[0], h[1], h[2], h[3])
```

А потом и строки:

```
for i in result:
    print(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3])
```

Последовательноть и название столбцов таблицы-источника должны полностью совпадать с кортежем "h"

Answer (score 0):

При использовании драйвера mysql.connector, в вышеприведенном примере, вместо

```
   cursor = conn.cursor()
```

следует использовать:

```
   cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Тогда результат можно выводить в виде print(row['agrm_id']);